# How to go with well-known classes and interfaces in an UML class diagram

Tags: uml

Given I have two Java classes `Foo` and `Bar`, and `Bar` has a `getFoos()` method that returns a `List<Foo>`.

In Java, all classes extend the parent class `Object`. `List` is an interface that extends the interface `Collection`, which in turn extends `Iterable`. All of these are provided by the Java core and do not require programming. However, they have methods that can be used or overridden. Interface hierarchy may be necessary to be known, for example a method that takes an `Iterable<Foo>` will accept a `List<Foo>`.

When drawing a class diagram from these in UML, how do I do with the well-known classes (`Object`) and interfaces (`List`, and its super interfaces `Collection` and `Iterable`)? Do I have to draw them into the diagram as well? Can I skip them completely? Is there a special symbol for these (a cloud would feel great to me)? What about not-that-common classes that should be qualified (i.e. if it would be an `java.awt.List` and not a `java.util.List`)?

Comment: UML is a bit like martial arts. Every practitioner has their own style/flavor. I would consult the people who will consume that UML about what they expect. Bloating it with Java Hierarchies is most probably not a good idea (in general - with some exceptions, perhaps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice for how to deal with well-known classes will depend on how you plan on using your UML class diagram.

If the main purpose for creating a UML diagram is to communicate design details to a team, I would opt for **not** including well-know classes (not just from the JDK but also classes that are well-known in your context). The reason being that you want your message to be focused. Adding these well-known classes can quickly clutter your diagram while adding nothing to your message. For the same reason I typically exclude getters/setters and any information that is not essential to understanding the design. For classes that are not well-known I will include them because they communicate information that is not easily accessible to the team.

If your class diagram is going to be used in MDA, i.e. it will be used to generate a system implementation, then you have to include well-known classes.

Comment: I decided not to include all of them, and to draw a cloud (which was actually possible with the editor I have to use) with just the full qualified class name for classes I absolutely need for clarification (which were `Exception`, `RuntimeException` and `Enum`). This may be non-standard, but it was accepted as sufficient work.

Answer (score 4):

UML is not linked to any language, there is nothing in the norm about JDK classes.

A lot's of tools provide a profile with JDK classes already defined.

So you have to look in your tool if you get menu like "import profile" and look which profiles are available.

Two others solutions could be:

- Define in your models the minimum set of JDK classes you need
- Trying to write a java program to generate the XMI of JDK classes. Theoretically not so complicated, but the JDK includes JNI classes on which the introspection can not be used.

Comment: I agree that most of tools, supporting Java generation from UML, already have a model (library) where all JDK classes are defined.
You can also rmodel the desired JDK classes or reverse the JDK....