# Constructor in visual paradigm

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

How can you take a HashMap of type, for example, `<Person,Integer>`, as a parameter for the constructor in class diagrams? Every time I try in visual paradigm, it gives an error.

Comment: Error like "Hey, it does not work"? Please post a description of that error or you won't see any answer.

Comment: have you look to this question first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589182/how-to-go-with-well-known-classes-and-interfaces-in-an-uml-class-diagram

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what error you were getting, but what you wanted to achieve can be done by performing the steps in Visual Paradigm.

1. Add a constructor into the class by right clicking on the class and selecting Add > Constructor.
2. Right click on the constructor and select Open Specification...
3. Under the Parameters tab, click Add...
4. Enter the parameter name, enter java.util.HashMap as type and  as Type modifier. If you want only a diagram for presentation purpose without the need of code generation, you may enter HashMap without entering 'java.util.HashMap'

Done!

The article below provides you with more information about their Class Diagram support. Hope this helps.
https://circle.visual-paradigm.com/docs/uml-and-sysml/class-diagram/how-to-draw-a-class-diagram-in-uml/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]